# Using tkinter how do I reposition my tree view to top left corner

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to reposition my treeview to top left corner but not sure if I am using the grid command correctly are the view just isn't moving. codes are below

also added pic of where I want it to move.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()

frm = Frame(root)
frm.pack(padx=0,pady=10)

tv = ttk.Treeview(frm,columns=(1,2),show = 'headings',height='20')
tv.grid(row=5,column=0)
#tv.pack()

tv.heading(1,text='Date')
tv.heading(2,text='Value')
root.title('New Data')
root.geometry('650x500')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `frm.pack(padx=0, pady=10, anchor='nw')`.

Comment: perfect! that worked thanks v much !